# Is the function $f(x)=x^2$ absolutely continuous on the real line?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, lipschitz-functions

In Wiki (Lipschitz), it says:

> A Lipschitz function $g : \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is absolutely continuous.

According to the definition of absolute continuity, I am confused about an simple example:

$$f(x) = x^2$$

This is **not** a Lipschitz function since we cannot find a bounded $L$ such that

$$|f(y) - f(x)| \leq L||y-x||_2$$

But is $f(x)$ absolutely continuous? (I am confused about if $x$ approaches $\infty$)

Comment: This wiki page says $x^2$ is not absolutely continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity  I look forward to seeing an explanation for it.

Comment: I see. For a fixed $|y_k-x_k|$, i.e. $\delta$ is fixed and bounded, $|f(y_k) - f(x_k)|$ is not bounded as $y_k$ and $x_k$ $\rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For function on the real line, one has the  following chain of inclusions (adapted from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity), which considers only a compact subset):

> Differentiable with a bounded derivative $\subset$ Lipschitz continuous $\subset$ absolutely continuous $\subset$ uniformly continuous  $\subset$ continuous

None of the inclusions are difficult to prove: use, left to right,

1. Mean Value Theorem
2. Triangle inequality
3. Definition of absolute continuity specialized to one interval
4. Definition of uniform continuity

All inclusions are strict, by the way.

The function $f(x)=x^2$ is not uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, and therefore is not absolutely continuous.